# How to use Jquery inside Google maps InfoWindow?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I want to show jQuery effects (show and hide divs) inside the Google maps InfoWindow, how can I do this?

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of information.  Have you just tried it yet?  You can put HTML inside the InfoWindow; so what happens when you put a DIV inside the window and try to manipulate it with jQuery?

Comment: yes that is what I actually did, but Jquery doesn't affect anything , while i did the same for the div but outside the InfoWindow and it worked fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though I have personalty not yet tried it,  this -> http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/ plugin should provide the functionality you are searching for.

Hope it helps! Have fun :)

Comment: thanks , but what I'm searching for is using jquery inside the Infowindow :)

Answer (score 5):

The InfoWindow can take a DOM-object as content. So create one, and then get the jQuery-reference to it, like this:

```
var layer = document.createElement("div");
layer.innerText="Click to hide!";
$(layer).click(function(){ $(layer).hide('slow'); } );

infoWindow.setContent(layer); //something like this
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...})

//Create infowindow
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Some content"
});

//Link infowindow to marker in map
infowindow.open(map,marker);

//Add a listener
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
    $( '.gira' ).change(function(){alert('a')})
})
```

From API Ref: This event is fired when the  containing the InfoWindow's content is attached to the DOM