# Google Maps, show infoWindow on Load and addListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a Google Map script that allows me to show markers with infowindows on a map. My concern is:

a) How can I open and set the content of each infoWindow ONLOAD, so all infoWindows popup?

b) How can I make it possible for jQuery to "listen" to the content of the marker's infoWindow? My a-Tag inside has a class "show" and I have a simple document.ready $('.show').click(function()) which doesn't do anything while clicking on the a-tag inside the window. Outside of Gmaps it works fine.

Hope you can help, below the script I use:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var infowindow = null;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            initialize();
        });

        function initialize() {
            var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(38, 10);

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: centerMap,
                scrollwheel: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);

            setMarkers(map, sites);
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "loading..."
            });

            var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
            bikeLayer.setMap(map);
        }

        var sites = [
            ['Test', 38, 10, 1, '<a href="#" class="show" data-popup="1"><img class="marker_class" src="91ccd318ae8b607500f54e7c56b5350e.png" alt="Preview"></a>']
        ];

        function setMarkers(map, markers) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var sites = markers[i];
                var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: siteLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: sites[0],
                    zIndex: sites[3],
                    html: sites[4]
                });

                var contentString = "Google Maps";

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            }
        }
    </script>

    <div id="gmap" class="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can open your infowindow right after you create it like:

```
            infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Also, I think this would answer your question about using jQuery in InfoWindow:
[How to use Jquery inside Google maps InfoWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075453/how-to-use-jquery-inside-google-maps-infowindow#8114361)

You can pass an dom object to the infowindow, which you can set a listener to.